# Entity Framework - Making a column auto-incremement

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle, entity-framework

So I'm using the Entity Framework and we have a modal for a table called TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES.  This table has a column called NOTEID which is a number.  Right now, when we create a new row, we get the next available number with this code:

```
note.NOTEID = (from n in context.TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES
               orderby n.NOTEID descending
               select n.NOTEID).Max() + 1;
```

To me, this seems incredibly hacky (I mean you have to do an entire SQL query just to get the next value).  Plus, it's incredibly dangerous; it's not thread safe or transaction safe.  I've already found 9 instances in the DB that have the same NOTEID!  Good thing no one even thought to put a UNIQUE constraint on that column... sigh.

So anyway, I've added a new sequence to the database:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES_SEQ START WITH 732 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Now my question:

How do I instruct the Entity framework to use TPM_PROJECTVERSIONNOTES_SEQ.nextval when inserting a row into this table?  Basically, I just don't want to specify a NOTEID at all and I want the framework to take care of it for me.  It's been suggested I use a trigger, but I think this is a bit hacky and would rather have to Entity framework just create the correct SQL in the first place.  I'm using Oracle 11g for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically generate identity for an Oracle database through Entity framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227962/how-to-automatically-generate-identity-for-an-oracle-database-through-entity-fram)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate. This question is asking for a solution that does not use a trigger. The linked possible duplicate's answer involved a trigger.

Comment: @Shannon: It is not about what the question is asking but about what is possible and EF simply don't do anything to get next value from sequence (unless this is specifically coded in provider for Oracle and as I know it is not). It expects that Id assignment will happen in DB = it requires trigger.

Comment: @Ladislav: I think whether questions are duplicates or not does depend on what is being asked, not on what is possible. The other Q&A doesn't make clear, as far as I could tell, that the trigger was the only way, so does not answer Mike's question, and future people with the same question, of "Is there a way to do it without a trigger." So I think Mike's question might have value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this may still fall into what you call the 'hacky' category, you can avoid using triggers to call the nextval, but you must utilize a stored procedure to handle the insert (whereas it will call the nextval in lieu of using a TRIGGER).  (I guess this could fall more into a TAPI/XAPI category)

Check out the recent article 
[TECHNOLOGY: Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html)

it explains (and contains samples) to using a stored procedure to handle the insert, calling the sequence, and mapping it back to the ODP EF BETA.

This obviously does not have the ODP EF Beta do the SQL for nextval, but it is an alternative.  (look at this forum, it does appear that most of the EF Oracle frameworks fall victim to this-- devart etc {https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2184372} )

Comment: Yup, I did a bunch of research on this subject.  The short answer is Oracle sequences just suck - You can't default to them, triggers have a performance impact, the Entity framework hates them, if you ever want to bulk copy or replicate your data, it's a PITA, the list goes on.  I'm now strongly considering switching over to UUIDs as primary keys where appropriate.  I've always been a fan of that design in MS SQL and Postgres anyway.