# Generate identity for an Oracle database through Entity Framework using an exisiting stored procedure

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4, oracle11g, repository-pattern, identity-column

How to automatically generate identity for an Oracle database through Entity Framework?

I have a function that I could call and generate the column which is not in the context how do I explicitly call the stored procedure through Entity Framework? I am using a repository pattern.

Random Number generator to insert a record (where I get the primary key through a UDF and pass this to the entity to insert).

Answer (score 1):

**1) Create sequence in Oracle**

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE dummy_test_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```

**2)Create property**

```
   sealed public class CommonUtilities
    {
      #region Sequences
       public static int DummyTestSeq
        {
         get
          {              
            using (Entities ctx = new Entities()) 
             { 
               return Convert.ToInt32(ctx.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>("SELECT dummy_test_seq.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL").ToList().Single()); 
              }  
            }
         }
    #endregion
}
```

**3)Getting Sequence**

```
   public int InsertTable1()
    {
      using (Entities ctx = new Entities())
        {
            ctx.tabel1.Add(new tabel1()
            {
                SEQ = CommonUtilities.DummyTestSeq,
                Date= DateTime.Now
            });
            return ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
     }
```